# what is a errors in the code sql pluse

Tags: sql

```
create table pilots (
  pilots_id varchar2(50),
  pilots_name varchar2(50),
  pilots_adress varchar2(50),
  pilots_city varchar2(50),
  pilots_state varchar2(50),
  pilots_zipe varchar2(50),
  pilots_phone varchar(50),
  CONSTRANT pilots_pk PRIMARY KEY (pilots_id)
);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: CONSTRANT should be CONSTRAINT with an I but that depends on the database like @GordonLinoff said. The syntax may even be wrong depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CREATE TABLE pilots (
    pilots_id varchar(50),
    pilots_name varchar(50),
    pilots_adress varchar(50),
    pilots_city varchar(50),
    pilots_state varchar(50),
    pilots_zipe varchar(50),
    pilots_phone varchar(50),
    CONSTRAINT pilots_pk PRIMARY KEY (pilots_id)
)
```